# swift include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FacebookSDK.FBAppLinkResolver''

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook, paypal, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have added the PayPal cocoa pod and then added the Facebook SDK into my project and have the errors:

```
include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FacebookSDK.FBAppLinkResolver'and Could not build module 'FacebookSDK''
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Thanks, I am using Xcode 7 and Swift